# loop through a list of objects of classes

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I am stuck with deleting an element from the list if the user enters a value is in the object of that list. so I am trying to build a shopping cart and there is a method called remove_item(). it will accept the name of the item you want to remove as a string. then loop through an object of class itemToPurchase to check it's attribute. if we find it we remove the whole object from the list if not continue loping and if we didn't find it in the whole loop through  an except and continue

```
cart_item = [] 

def remove_item(self, remove):   
        try:
            for item in cart_item:
            #print(item.item_name)
            if(item.item_name == remove):
                cart_item.remove(item)
                print('item removed')
            else:
                raise ValueError('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.')
    except ValueError as excpt:
        print(excpt)
```

Comment: Your previous question was helpfully formatted in shape, but please take care of it yourself. Indentation is really, *really* important in Python, and there is always a chance a helpful editor changes it to be 'correct' whereas your own code is wrong. You may not have noticed it but there is a Preview available while you are writing your question.

Answer (score -1):

Little modification in you code

**Try this:-**

```
def remove_item(ramove):
    cart_item = ["apple","orange"]
    try:
        for item in cart_item:
            if ramove in item:
                cart_item.remove(item)
                return cart_item
            else:
                raise ValueError('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed.')
    except ValueError as excpt:
        print(excpt)
```

Comment: you can use "ramove==item"" as well here